# tiles() method list won't mutate within class

Tags: python, list, class

Below is a class for a rectangular room of width and height. With a floor of tiles number width by height. I'm initially making a list of lists of tiles set to False as they are not cleaned but in "cleanTileAtPosition(pos)" we are setting the tile list element tiles[x_tile][y_tile] to True but when called in another method and when immediately printed out the element is not changed to True. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong or is this something to do with Classes I am missing?

```
class RectangularRoom(object):
"""
A RectangularRoom represents a rectangular region containing clean or dirty
tiles.

A room has a width and a height and contains (width * height) tiles. At any
particular time, each of these tiles is either clean or dirty.
"""
def __init__(self, width, height):
    """
    Initializes a rectangular room with the specified width and height.

    Initially, no tiles in the room have been cleaned.

    width: an integer > 0
    height: an integer > 0
    """

    self.width = width
    self.height = height

def tiles(self):
    """
    Initialise a list of rows and columns of tiles that are False if not cleaned and true if cleaned
    """

    return [[False] * self.height for i in range(self.width)]


def cleanTileAtPosition(self, pos):
    """
    Mark the tile under the position POS as cleaned.

    Assumes that POS represents a valid position inside this room.

    pos: a Position - pos is a tuple (x, y)
    """


    (x_tile, y_tile) = (int(math.floor(pos.getX())), int(math.floor(pos.getY())))

    #print (x_tile, y_tile)

    self.tiles()[x_tile][y_tile] = True



def isTileCleaned(self, m, n):
    """
    Return True if the tile (m, n) has been cleaned.

    Assumes that (m, n) represents a valid tile inside the room.

    m: an integer
    n: an integer
    returns: True if (m, n) is cleaned, False otherwise
    """
    self.m = m
    self.n = n

    if self.tiles()[self.m][self.n] == True:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def getNumTiles(self):
    """
    Return the total number of tiles in the room.

    returns: an integer
    """

    return self.width*self.height

def getNumCleanedTiles(self):
    """
    Return the total number of clean tiles in the room.

    returns: an integer
    """
    numCleanTiles = 0

    for row in range(self.width):
        for column in range(self.height):
            if self.tiles()[row][column] == True:
                numCleanTiles +=1

    return numCleanTiles

def getRandomPosition(self):
    """
    Return a random position inside the room.

    returns: a Position object.
    """
    #
    return Position(random.randrange(0, self.width), random.randrange(0, self.height))

def isPositionInRoom(self, pos):
    """
    Return True if pos is inside the room.

    pos: a Position object.
    returns: True if pos is in the room, False otherwise.
    """
    if 0 <= pos.getX() < self.width and 0 <= pos.getY() < self.height:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: No you can't, that doesn't create 4 separate lists but 4 references to same list instead. If you do that and do `grid[2][2] = True` then `grid[1][2]` will be `True` as well.

Comment: @niemmi Good point, I don't know what I was thinking

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're calling `tiles()` function that always creates a new grid. Have your `__init__` function to initialize the grid and assign it to `self.tiles` the same way you initialize `self.width` and `self.height`. Then just use `self.tiles` everywhere instead of calling `self.tiles()` that can be removed.

Comment: Thanks muchly - that makes all the difference. I wasn't aware one could define self.title when title wasn't a variable name.

Comment: You're welcome. You can set instance variables in `__init__` or any other member function no matter if you pass the value as a parameter or not.